# Drag one elemt intobox and remove another on same time using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drag

I have a problem with jQuery

i want to drag and drop a image into a box I have 4 images but i want only one image drag and drop into the box if we add another image into box first image come back on to original-position 
i want this using jQuery drag and drop function.

[

jQuery(".draggable").draggable({
        revert:  function(dropped) {

```
         var draggable = jQuery(this),
             hasBeenDroppedBefore = draggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
             wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "stage-a";
         if(wasJustDropped) {
             // don't revert, it's in the droppable
             return false;
         } ]
```

Refrance page http://www.premierprotein.com/protein-101

Comment: Some sample code on what you have tried?

Comment: ok i added please check

Comment: Edit your post and paste the code there and format it please.

Comment: yes i added please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you might try this, I tested this using jQuery version **1.8.3 & jquery-ui 1.9.1**

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swap elements</title>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .droppable {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .draggable {
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      background: yellow;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
    }
    .ui-draggable-dragging {
      background: blue;
    }

    .hoverClass {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='droppable'>
    <div class="draggable">Draggable 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class='droppable'>
    <div class="draggable">Draggable 2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      window.startPos = window.endPos = {};

      makeDraggable();

      $('.droppable').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hoverClass',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          var $from = $(ui.draggable),
              $fromParent = $from.parent(),
              $to = $(this).children(),
              $toParent = $(this);

          window.endPos = $to.offset();

          swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 200);
          swap($to, window.endPos, window.startPos, 1000, function() {
            $toParent.html($from.css({position: 'relative', left: '', top: '', 'z-index': ''}));
            $fromParent.html($to.css({position: 'relative', left: '', top: '', 'z-index': ''}));
            makeDraggable();
          });
        }
      });

      function makeDraggable() {
        $('.draggable').draggable({
          zIndex: 99999,
          revert: 'invalid',
          start: function(event, ui) {
            window.startPos = $(this).offset();
          }
        });
      }

      function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
        $el.css('position', 'absolute')
          .css(fromPos)
          .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
            if (callback) callback();
          });
      }
    });
```

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: You have any reference site